# How to plot colorbar with specific range of value in Matlab

Tags: matrix, plot, colorbar

I have a colorized lines and I want to plot the colorbar for those line with specific value. The lines are colorized by RGB value. Now I want to change the value of the colorbar to another range of value. I mean, I need only change the range of shown value in colorbar to another range. in this [Link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02872627357370195223), there is my original output for color bar and I want to change the value the color bar to another range of value like [This](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73768643315988479345). 
This is my code that I have written by all the time it shows me my original range not my define range

```
hold on
for k = 1:Num_Line_SIFTS
 plot3([SIFT_1((k,1),SIFT_2((k,1)],[SIFT_1((k,2),SIFT_2((k,2)],[SIFT_1((k,3),SIFT_2((k,3)],...
       'o-','Color',[RGB_0_1(k,1) RGB_0_1(k,2) RGB_0_1(k,3)],'MarkerFaceColor',[RGB_0_1(k,1) RGB_0_1(k,2) RGB_0_1(k,3)],'MarkerEdgeColor',...
       'k', 'LineWidth',2)
end

h = colorbar;
set(h,'xlim', [ min(min(Uncertainty_Distances_between_SIFTs))  max(max(Uncertainty_Distances_between_SIFTs))])

hold off
```

can anybody help me for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out 'Ytick' and 'YtickLabel'. The first is used to define the points (values) of your color bar (what you say as original range) that you want a tick to show. In your figure these points/values are 10,20,30...60. The 'YtickLabel' property on the other hand defines what will be displayed in the Ytick positions (what you mention as the defined range if I understand correctly). 
Consequently you can create a colorbar, get its handle:

```
h = colorbar;
```

and then:
a) Decide how many values you want to 'tick' in the colorbar (in this example the original six):

```
set(h,'Ytick',linspace(10,60,6));
```

b) Decide what value will be displayed in each of the 'ticks'

```
set(h,'Yticklabel', linspace(min(min(Uncertainty_Distances_between_SIFTs)),  max(max(Uncertainty_Distances_between_SIFTs)),6));
```

You can also display completely arbitrary values as ticklabels, even text:

```
set(h,'Yticklabel',{'a','b','c'});
```

If the provided ticklabel values are less than the ticks defined, the ticklabels will loop.